# Is it possible to get the number of arguments on a variadic function?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

I've been looking into how to declare functions or class members with a variable number of argument, and came across variadic functions, however I was wondering if there was some way to access the number of arguments pass to the function, *without having to pass it directly as a first argument*,  as most of the documentation presents. I am also aware that I can use either variadic templates or `std::initializer_list`, but since I was looking to pass multiple arguments *of the same type*, those seem both too generic and/or with a convoluted syntax.

```
#include <cstdarg>

bool func(int args...) {
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, args);   
    int val = args;
    while(val >=0) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
        val = va_arg(list, int);
    }
    return true;
}

bool other_func(int c, int args...) {
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, args);   
    int val = args;
    for (int i = 0; i<c; i++) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
        val = va_arg(list, int);
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    func(2, 7, 47, -1, 23 /* ignored */);
    other_func(3 /* n of parameters */, 2, 7, 47);

    return 0;
}
```

In these particular example, `func` loops over the input arguments until a negative value is found (in order to illustrate the issue and force a stop flag) while `other_func` requires the number of arguments to be passed as the first argument. Both these implementations seemed to me rather flawed and unsafe, is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Can you use C++11 or later?

Comment: There is almost no valid use case for variadic functions in modern C++. In you case, depending on requirements, why don't you simply use a container (list, vector, array...) or indeed, std::initialiser_list to pass multiple arguments of the same type?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you're not calling `va_end` in either of your functions.  This would be a strong reason to prefer a C++ approach.

Answer (score 8):

> since I was looking to pass multiple arguments *of the same type*

That's exactly what `std::initialiser_list<int>` would give you.

You seem to be mistaken about variadic functions. The declaration `int args...` doesn't mean "some amount of `int` arguments", instead it means "one `int` named args, followed by any number of arguments of any type"

Comment: Yes it seems that I misintrepeted what `int args...` entails. My main issue with `initializer_lists` is that I need the bracket initializer for passing a variable number of arguments, but I guess it is the simpler approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you use C-style varargs then no, you can only parse the argument list one at a time.

If you have the option of c++11 then you could use a variadic template function instead and use the sizeof... operator to get the size of the argument pack.

```
template<typename ... Args>
void func(char * leading, Args const & ... args)
{
  /* sizeof...(Args) will give you the number of arguments */
}
```

Comment: Note that this creates a different function for all calls that have differing numbers of arguments and/or differing types. This can be useful so long as the function doesn't retain, and use state on subsequent calls.

Comment: Is there way to specify a single type for `Args`. One of the main issues with a generic template is that it may cause ambiguity if the function has overloads with different type, but fixed number, of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you have C++17 available to you, this can all be done at compile time with a variadic non-type template argument and a fold expression: ([Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MptXu6KooOt04KOL))

```
template<int... args>
constexpr bool func() {
    return ((args < 0) || ...);
}


int main() {
    static_assert(func<2, 7, 47, -1, 23>());
    static_assert(!func<1, 2, 3>());

    return 0;
}
```

(and if you're using C++20, you can enforce compile-time computation with `consteval` instead of `constexpr`. [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DvSoAPXOUSawnmwg))

---

If you're stuck with C++11, then you can still do it at compile-time, but we'll need some more boilerplate ([Live Demo 3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F3AXZdRDG8elDSwf))

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template<bool...>
    struct disjunction;
    
    template<bool b>
    struct disjunction<b> : std::integral_constant<bool, b>
    {};
     
    template<bool left, bool... Bs>
    struct disjunction<left, Bs...> : std::conditional<left, disjunction<left>, disjunction<Bs...>>::type
    {};
}

template<int... args>
constexpr bool func() {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) > 0, "Need to pass more than 1 integer");
    return detail::disjunction<(args < 0)...>::value;
}


int main() {
    static_assert(func<2, 7, 47, -1, 23>(), "There is one negative number");
    static_assert(!func<1, 2, 3>(), "There aren't any negative numbers");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard-conforming way to detect the number of arguments passed to a (C-style) variadic function. You would have to pass the number in an initial argument, or use some sort of terminator that could be recognized as the end of the sequence. It would be preferable to use C++ facilities for this.

Comment: By "C++ facilities" I assume you are referring to variadic templates and/or initializer lists, right. I am also not quite sure what is the diference  between a "C" and a "C++" variadic function.

Comment: @joaocandre usually "C variadic function" is variadic function and "C++ variadic function" is variadic function template

Answer (score 0):

If you have guaranteed values for arguments which are invalid in the present case you can use a macro to call your actual function. This works well with pointers where you can probably use NULL as a tombstone argument instead of -1 in the example below.

```
#define add_positives(...) _add_positives(-1, __VA_ARGS__, -1)
int _add_positives(int n, ...) {
    int res = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);

    while (1) {
        int i = va_arg(ap, int);
        if (i < -1) break;
        res += i;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return res;
}
```